# Problem with Solid State Relay based on MOC3061

Tags: solid-state-relay, triac

I was experimenting the circuit below. In the load, I placed the input of a full bridge rectifier. The issue is that the power triac is never activated. Sounds like the zero cross is not working.

Is that because a bridge rectifier is not a proper load for this circuit?

I simulated trying with an opto with no zero cross, and the simulation worked.

[image: Hot-Line Switching Application Circuit]

Comment: could be that the optocoupler doesn't like the long deat time you get with the bridge rectifier.

Comment: Could be. Do you think there's a way to solve that?

Comment: use a non zero-crossing optioisolator. eg: MOC3021

Answer (score 1):

The load needs to draw more current than the gate trigger current of the triac in the relevant two quadrants for the triac to turn on.

Try putting a substantial resistive load on the output of the simulated bridge rectifier (eg. 200 ohms).

Comment: Tried, but still the same.

Comment: use an incandescent light bulb

Comment: Yes, but adding that bulb wouldn't be a practical solution. I think I will get rid of this circuit, and will use a simple electromechanical relay.